# benefits of upgrading form pingfederate 6.x to 7?

Tags: pingfederate

Hi Can some one tell me the high level points on the benefits of upgrading from pingfederate 6.x to 7.7?
want to know the pros and cons of upgrading from version 6.x to 7

Comment: It would be beneficial if you noted what version you are currently on. The discussion is very different, for example, if you're 6.11 vs. 6.2. In addition, what "adapters" are you using? ReferenceID? IWA? These all make differences when having a pro/con discussion. As a side note... I think that you asked this question in our community - did you not? https://www.pingidentity.com/support/answers/index.cfm/pros-and-cons-of-upgrading-pingfederate-from-6-x-to-7-x?id=90640000000L8WSAA0

Comment: Hi Andy. we are using version 6.10.1 and thinking of upgrading to 7

Answer (score 2):

A very comprehensive list of what has changed in every PingFederate release is included in the release notes: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=zyv1564002949656.html

As Andy mentioned above it does depend on what aspects of the product you're using, and what exact version of 6.x you're on (as there were many).  7.x has some new protocols that may be of interest to you, improved interoperability with 3rd party products, administrative and performance enhancements.  There really aren't that many "cons" to it - the upgrade should be very quick and smooth for you.

Comment: mostly we use only SAML federation and is integrated with siteminder